# Cannot convert CGPoint, or CGFloat to a Double in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, type-conversion

I am writing a function that takes a CGPoint and CGFloat, then it takes both of those values and then subtracts them in Swift. I am having trouble whenever I try using the Double() for both the CGFloat and CGPoint.  I have tried using other value conversions but no matter what I try to convert the CGPoints and CGFloats to, I always get an error saying, I cannot apply "-" to operands of Double, CGFloat, Int etc..

```
    func findTheDifference(location: CGPoint) -> Double {
    let position = sprite.position.y
    let difference = position - location
    return difference
    }
```

Comment: well you are subtracting a CGPoint from a double. You are saying (2, 3) - 5. That doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to do arithmetic on a struct and a float... that's not going to work.

If you're trying to find the difference between the x and y components, you would do:

```
func findTheDifference(location: CGPoint) -> Double {
    return location.y - location.x
}
```

If you're trying to find the distance between two points (sprite.position and location), you would use the distance formula: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

```
func findTheDistance(point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint) -> Double {
    let xDist = Double(point2.x - point1.x)
    let yDist = Double(point2.y - point1.y)
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist))
}
let location = // get location
let distance = findTheDistance(sprite.position, location)
```

If you're just trying to find the difference between the y components:

```
func findTheDifference(location: CGPoint) -> Double {
    return Double(sprite.position.y - location.y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the y of the location

```
return position - location.y
```